# Crystal Reports - How to have special condition within Group

Tags: crystal-reports, where-clause

In my report I currently group products based on the first 4 letters of their product code, I would like to have an exception where if those 4 letters say are 'LBUS" then I want to group them with anything that is "LBCN' everything else would just be grouped individually ?

Answer (score 0):

Group on a formula with a logic like this:

```
IF (LEFT({prod.code}, 4) = "LBUS" or LEFT({prod.code}, 4) = "LBCN") Then "LBCN"
ELSE LEFT({prod.code}, 4)
```